# Creating List of objects from Dynamic Tables

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, list, methods

I am relatively new to .NET from 12 yrs on PHP. I created a MVC project. In my project, I created a class in the Models that has a Public method that creates a LIST of items that can be manipulated as needed anywhere in the project as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MYPROJECT.Models
{
    public class Common
    {
             public List<Tablex> CommonList(int limit )
        {
            var theList = db.Tablex.Take(limit).ToList();

            return theList;
        }
    }
}
```

To call the list in a view for instance, I do something like this and it works fine:

```
@{
    var thecommon = new MYPROJECT.Models.Common();
    var sessions = thecommon.CommonList(45);
}
@foreach (var item in sessions)
     {
       @Html.Raw("<div class="someclass">"+item.column1+" >> "+item.column2+"</div>");
     }
```

Now,...

I would like to make Tablex so that I can call any table as needed, and adjust the columns i,j as needed in my views or other controllers.

Any idea how to proceed?

PS: As you can possibly tell, this list is populated by inputs in the database table

Comment: Not sure if I've understand correctly. Do you want at **Common** class Tablex will be replaced by any table?

Comment: Thanks for the willingness to help dbardelas. I want the CommonList() method in the Common class to return a list of objects from the table I pass to it. In other words, to make Tablex dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by running a Raw query. I can pass the table or the columns dynamically and then create a list object from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
public List<T> CommonList(IEnumerable<T> table, int limit)
{
    var theList = table.Take(limit).ToList();

    return theList;
}
```

Comment: It did not work unfortunately. I will continue to dig around and I am sure I will find a way because I read somewhere it's doable.